# Does many-to-many relationship design properly

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I have created two tables based on Hibernate that have **many-to-many** relationship to each other.

The tables:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Interests")
data class Interest(
    var description: String = "") : PanacheEntity()

@Entity
@Table(name = "Accounts")
data class Account(@field:Id var id: UUID? = null,
                   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) var gender: Gender? = null,
                   var birthday: Long = 0,
                   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST])
                   @JoinTable(
                       name = "user_interests",
                       joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "user_id")],
                       inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "interest_id")]
                   )
                   var interests: List<Interest> = listOf()) : PanacheEntityBase
```

Behind the scenes, Hibernate creates a separate table to hold the foreign keys. Here is the generated DDL:

```
create table user_interests
(
    user_id     uuid   not null
        constraint fkfxfdgodf1o1gxd8offdxrhcwu
            references accounts,
    interest_id bigint not null
        constraint fkdtbf68t9l8ehm46bi6ko45kb5
            references interests
);
```

The question is, what are the cryptic strings after the **constraint** and is the DDL correctly defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Interest class, declare "var accounts: List" too, with inverse mapping!